How to modifying a data table with openxlsx2?
The data
We have an Excel data table, named data_table, in the sheet S1, positioned at an unknown position.

The goal
We want to load the file, modify the colum COL_1, and save the file with the modified data table. The best would be for the formatting and equations to remain unchanged.
Current solution
For now I have to delete the previous data table to modify it:
library(openxlsx2)

# Load the workbook
wb <- wb_load("data_table_test.xlsx")

# Get the data tables info
data_tables_info <- wb_get_tables(wb, sheet = "S1")

# Get the data table position
data_table_pos <- data_tables_info$tab_ref[data_tables_info$tab_name == "data_table"]

# Read the data table
data_table <- wb_to_df(wb, sheet = "S1", dims = data_table_pos)

# modify the data table
data_table$COL_1 <- as.integer(data_table$COL_1) + 1000

# remove the data table from the worksheet
wb <- wb_remove_tables(wb, sheet = "S1", table = "data_table")

# write the data back to the data table
wb <- wb_add_data_table(wb, x = data_table, dims = data_table_pos, sheet = "S1", table_name = "data_table")

# Save the workbook
wb_save(wb, "data_table_test_out.xlsx")

Question
How to modify the data of a data table in a worksheet ?

This question has been answered in the openxlsx2 discussion board
